# why sqlite not updating row

Tags: android, sqlite

**hi
I'm tired of searching and reviewing my code
please help me!
I want to update a row in table,  I think the update because when show value with(toast) i see row updated but  when I close activity and open it value not change

where is probles code:**

***DataBaseHelper:***

```
    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "";  
private static String DB_NAME ="surbiks";
private final Context mContext; 
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;


static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION );

    this.mContext = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    createDataBase();
}



private void copyDataBase(){

    try {

        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open("db/images.db");
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0){
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public boolean open() throws SQLException
{  

    try {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        mDataBase=this.getWritableDatabase();
        return mDataBase != null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() 
{
    if(mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
```

}

***and my update code in DataBaseHelper***

```
public  void set( ){

    open();
        String sql="update item_body set fav='1' where id='1'";

         mDataBase.execSQL(sql);

        close();                
}
```

***or this:***

```
       public boolean updateContact() 
    {
       ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
       open();
     args.put("fav", "1");
        return mDataBase.update("item_body", args, " id='1' " , null) > 0;

    }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i edit my code
this is work
thanks

```
    private void createDataBase()
{
    try{
        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist)
        {
            //this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.getWritableDatabase();

             db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What are you doing on create ? If you are overwriting same value over and over again this will be the result.

Comment: thanks.   my main activity is : final DataBaseHelper ada = new DataBaseHelper(a1.this); and on create in databasehelper is empty i call createDataBase();

Comment: You just say
but I can not understand what is the problem